# middle column creates blank space when we delete it in row with css property justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I'm deleting the middle column in a 3 column row, the last column doesn't shifts to the left. The middle column space remains blank due to:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Is there any solution which will align my column side by side although I delete any column?

[image]

```
    <!--html-->
    <div class="module">
        <h2>flex working</h2>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex_inner">
                01 - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="flex_inner">
                02 - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="flex_inner">
                03 - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--css-->
    .flex {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

    .flex_inner {
            flex: 0 0 31%;
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }
<!--css end-->
```

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide your html and css code Then expect for solution

Comment: please suggest the solution for same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove justify-content: space-between and use a margin to created space between each div. Or you could use space-around instead and they won't stay on separate sides of the window.

```css
   .flex {
            display: flex;
           
        }

    .flex_inner {
            flex: 0 0 31%;
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="module">
        <h2>flex working</h2>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex_inner">
                01 - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="flex_inner">
                02 - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="flex_inner">
                03 - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please check it as an answer if this solved your problem :)